# How do I sort an Array with coffeescript?

Tags: arrays, sorting, coffeescript

with an Array like this:

```
users = [ 
   { id: 1, fname: 'Fred', lname: 'Flinstone', state: 'CA' }, 
   { id: 2, fname: 'George', lname: 'Winston', state: 'FL' },
   { id: 3, fname: 'Luke', lname: 'Skywalker', state: 'CA' }
]
```

and you want to sort by last name with coffeescript, you can do this:

```
users.sort (a,b) ->
  return if a.lname.toUpperCase() >= b.lname.toUpperCase() then 1 else -1
```

I tried using a function like this:

```
sortBy = (field, reverse, primer) ->
    key = (x) ->
      return if primer? then primer x[field] else x[field]
    return (a,b) ->
      A = key a
      B = key b
      return (A < B ? -1 : (A > B ? 1 : 0)) * [1,-1][+!!reverse]
```

which was invoked like this:

```
users.sort sortBy "lname", false, (a) -> 
  return a.toUpperCase()
```

but that didn't sort the array properly.

Is there a way to sort by more than 1 field, i.e. sort first by State, and then by Last Name?  I was hoping to improve upon the "sortBy" function above and add ability to sort by at least 2 fields.

Comment: What sort of thing might be "better" than that? (Actually I'd use `<=` and not `<` to help keep the sort stable.)

Comment: You can use the ternary operator there: `return a.lname.toUpperCase() > b.lname.toUpperCase() ? 1 : -1`

Comment: @BenLee: \*ahem\* The conditional operator.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, heh okay, I plead guildy to sloppy language :)

Comment: What does "better" and "failed" mean?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The conditional operator is the only ternary operator in the C-ish family of languages, including JavaScript, AFAICT. The term "ternary operator" has therefore long been considered synonymous with "conditional operator". "Conditional" is preferable, but "ternary" is perfectly valid.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: I didn't say that it wasn't.

Comment: @BenLee: No such thing in CoffeeScript, that would be some bizarre combination of the existential operator and an object literal in CoffeeScript.

Comment: @muistooshort, good point, I forgot CoffeeScript already uses those symbols for other purposes. I was thinking in terms of plain javascript.

Comment: @MarceloCantos, Lightness has a good point in this case specifically though because CoffeeScript's `if P then X else Y` actually *is* a ternary operator. It's just the conditional operator with different syntax.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Starting a sentence with, "*ahem*" carries a strong implication that, "What you said is wrong." You might not have *said* it, but you certainly implied it.

Comment: I actually prefer they typical ternary implementation too, less code than using coffeescript verbiage

Comment: @BenLee: What does that have to do with the point LightnessRacesInOrbit made?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a simpler way. Just re-use your generalized sorting function, and concatenate them using `||`:

```
sortBy = (key, a, b, r) ->
    r = if r then 1 else -1
    return -1*r if a[key] > b[key]
    return +1*r if a[key] < b[key]
    return 0

users.sort (a,b) ->
    sortBy('id', a, b, true) or
    sortBy('lname', a, b) or
    sortBy('fname', a, b)
```

Functions are cheap. You can then build an abstraction for that:

```
sortByMultiple = (a, b, keys) ->
    return r if (r = sortBy key, a, b) for key in keys
    return 0

users.sort (a,b) -> sortByMultiple a, b, ['id', 'lname', 'fname']
```

But then you lose the ability to set order or other parameters on each of them.

Comment: that's really slick.  I'm trying to understand how the 'or' works with chaining the functions.  Is it because it only moves to the next sortyBy function if the previous returns '0'?  Or perhaps another way to put it is it will keep sorting till first key is satisfied (i.e. '0') and then move to the next one?

Comment: Tested chaining the sortBy functions with or - works great!  Throwing sortByMultiple into the mix wasn't successful however, nothing was sorted correctly.  Thank you for a very helpful answer!

Comment: @jiy yes, that's pretty much it. Keep going until one of the criteria returns a non-zero value.

Comment: fixed the code for `sortByMultiple`, I forgot to pass the arguments around.

Answer (score 16):

Alternatively, you might want to consider using [Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)'s [sortBy](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#sortBy) so that you don't have to implement it yourself:

```
_(users).sortBy (u) -> [u.state, u.lname.toUpperCase()]
```

Comment: Thanks!  That looks extremely promising.  Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: The links in your answer no longer exist http://underscorejs.org/ and http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy are the new links

Answer (score 3):

This is something I thought would have implemented by default when using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs), but it isn't.

So here we are!

```
sortByLowercase: (collection, key) ->
    collection.sort (a, b) ->
      [av, bv] = [a[key], b[key]]
      [av, bv] = [av.toLowerCase(), bv.toLowerCase()]
      if av >= bv then 1 else if av <= bv then -1 else 0

sortByLowercase(users,'lname')
```

Based on a more generic example I found [here](https://gist.github.com/sj26/2698483)